# Django - Best method for serializing queryset into JSON format

Tags: python, json, django

I was trying two methods to serialize the field `attribute_value` of a queryset into JSON, and the fastest was not the one I tought it would. The field is an [HSTORE field](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-hstore) that is already formated for JSON

For instance:

```
print feature.attribute_value
>>>{"NOM": "Saguenay - Lac-Saint-Jean", "CODE": "45", "id": "0", "integer": "5"}
```

**First method:**

```
features_selected = Feature.objects.filter(shapefile__pk=shapefile_id).order_by("id")
data = [feature.attribute_value for feature in features_selected]
jsonData= json.dumps(data)
```

**Second method:**

```
features_selected = Feature.objects.filter(shapefile__pk=shapefile_id).order_by("id").values_list("attribute_value", flat=True)
jsonData= json.dumps(list(features_selected))
```

I tought the second method would be faster because only the field "attribute_value" is queryed instead of all (*) other fields in the first one, but the first was a little faster. I would like to know why, and if there could be a better way to serialize a queryset.

bump!

Comment: It could be that treating a queryset as a generator expression (as in `for feature in features_selected`) is faster than directly forcing evaluation into a list. I expect `list(features_selected)` to be slightly faster in the second example, but I don't think it would make a big difference. Anyway, this is purely speculation, you should use actual profiling to determine the exact cause. Also, is the first method consistently faster, or was this an incidental test?

Comment: What is `features_data` in the second method? Btw, your first method cries out for a list comprehension `data = [feature.attribute_value for feature in features_selected]`.